# Python script to save webpage and rename it while saving (save as - command)

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

Hi I searched a lot and ended up with no relevant results on how to save a webpage using python 2.6 and renaming it while saving.

Comment: search for in google. "python urllib get content write to file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better user requests libraty:

```
import requests

pagelink = "http://www.example.com"
page = requests.get(pagelink)

with open('/path/to/file/example.html', "w") as file:
    file.write(page.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the urllib(2) package to access the webpage, and then save the file object to the desired location (os.path).

It should look something like this:

```
import urllib2, os

pagelink = "http://www.example.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen(pagelink)

with open(os.path.join('/(full)path/to/Documents',pagelink), "w") as file:
    file.write(page)
```